# Java regular expression to extract content within square or round brackets

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract string within square or round. The string may have only square or round brackets

I am using the below regex.

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]|\\((.*?)\\)");`

The ouput string includes enclosing brackets also. Below is the code.

```
String example = "Example_(xxxxx)_AND_(yyyyy)_2019-01-28";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]|\\((.*?)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(example);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

The above pattern is giving output as

> > (xxxxx)
> >
> > (yyyyy)

Expected output is

> > xxxxx
> >
> > yyyyy

Comment: Group 1 should print `null` twice. Group 2 will have the output you need in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a regex that doesn't need to have alternation and can have only one group which you can uniquely access to get the value and even better if you use positive lookarounds to just capture your intended value using this regex,

```
(?<=[([])[^()[\]]*(?=[)\]])
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=[([])` - Positive look behind ensuring the preceding character is either `(` or `[`
- `[^()[\]]*` - Matches any character except opening or closing parenthesis
- `(?=[)\]])` - Positive look ahead to ensure it matches either `)` or `]`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/I1UjvQ/1)**

Sample Java codes,

```
String s = "Example_(xxxxx)_AND_(yyyyy)_2019-01-28";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=[(\\[])[^()\\[\\]]*(?=[)\\]])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Prints,

```
xxxxx
yyyyy
```

Alternatively, like I mentioned above, you can use this non-look around regex and capture just the group1 to get your content as this regex doesn't have any alternation hence only one group.

```
[([]([^()[\]]*)[)\]]
```

**[Demo without lookaround regex](https://regex101.com/r/I1UjvQ/2)**

Sample Java code with non-look around regex where you need to capture using `group(1)`

```
String s = "Example_(xxxxx)_AND_(yyyyy)_2019-01-28";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[(\\[]([^()\\[\\]]*)[)\\]]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Prints,

```
xxxxx
yyyyy
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a full example for you.

```
public class ExtractContentExample {

    private static final Pattern PATTERN2 = Pattern.compile("^[^\\(]{0,}\\(|([\\)][^\\(\\)]{1,}[\\(])|\\)[^\\)]{0,}$");

    public void test22212 () {
       String[] split = PATTERN2.split("(I )Comparison_(am )_AND_(so )_2019-01-28Comparison_(handsome!)");
       for (int i = 0; i< split.length; i++) {
           if (split[i] != null && !split[i].isEmpty()) {
               System.out.println(split[i]);
           }
       }
   }

}
```

I hope this will help

Comment: Your pattern gives partial result if the string contains space in between Ex: "Comparison_(xxxx, xxxx, xxxx)_AND_(yyyy, yyyy, yyyy)_2019-01-28". Gives output xxxx instead of xxxx, xxxx, xxxx

Answer (score 2):

You can use [lookahead and lookbehind](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):-

```
(?<=\[).*?(?=\])|(?<=\().*?(?=\))
```

or you can apply De Morgan's law to the above regex and use this:-

```
(?<=\[|\().*?(?=\]|\))
```

**Explanation**

`(?<=\[|\()` - preceded by `[` or `(`
`.*?` - any number of characters, non-greedy
`(?=\]|\))` - followed by `]` or `)`

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/x7s71s/1)

Comment: @RachanRK Where in your question have you mentioned that?